# Can frontend js framework be used for non-single page apps?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js, knockout.js

Someone told me that frontend frameworks such as backbone, angularjs, knockout, etc work only for **single-page** apps since one has to define routes based on **hashed arguments** and these frameworks trigger appropriate controllers/modals/views.

My question is can these frontend frameworks be used for non-single page apps as well ? Let's assume I have these three pages:

- index.html
- about.html
- contact.html

And I wrote code for routes in `app.js` included in above files. Then will these frameworks be able to figure out which page we are on and trigger appropriate controllers (and other stuff with modals, loading appropriate views) automatically unlike single page apps based on hashes? If possible, optionally can somebody give simple example of how to define routes (non-hased in this case ofcourse) for above three pages using any of above framework ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Yes. There is nothing that precludes you from building a traditional app with any of these frameworks and just "spicing" them up with more powerful client side interactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments there is nothing that precludes you from using any of these frameworks in a traditional, round-trip-per-page web application. That being said, **you should pick the right tool for the job.**

### **Disclaimer:**

*I have used both Angular and Knockout extensively on real world applications. I have only used backbone a little, but I **prefer** the declarative style of Angular and Knockout over the imperative style of backbone.*

Backbone and Angular are really designed and optimized for building single page applications. However, there are many shades of grey in between. You could load up a ***"Customers"*** page and have a handful of routes defined there, but when you navigate over to ***"Admin"*** that could be a total page refresh and you would have multiple routes defined there.

**Knockout is not a SPA framework**. It does not come with a router, and therefore doesn't handle side loading of views. You use something like Sammy.js to achieve the routing you want.

**If you aren't building a SPA then don't use a SPA framework.**

I would personally go with Knockout if I were you since you don't need a router.

However, if you plan to eventually build this out to a SPA, or a hybrid application, then go with a framework like [Angular](http://angularjs.org/), [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) or [Ember](http://emberjs.com/).

Comment: Note that if you do want to go over to an SPA after using Knockout, I'd look into Durandal which is a full framework built on Knockout.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly possible to do so.

the only difference will be that your ViewModel will be recreated every time you change page plus the data will be reloaded, but depending on the design of an app this is not much different from what you may do in a single page app.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular you can do something like follows to achieve this:

```
<html>
   <head>
     <title>index.html</title>
   </head>
   <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="indexController">
     <h2>{{title}}</h2>

     <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(app) {

            var indexController($scope) {
                $scope.title = "Index title!";
            };

            app.controller('indexController', ['$scope', indexController]);

        }(angular.module('myApp')));
     </script>    
   </body>
</html>
```

Knockout for example is not a full blown SPA framework. If you want routing you will have to  rely on 3rd party libraries, i.e. sammy.js